# Deleting conditional formatting on blanks withing range

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to delete conditional formatting of blanks within the range,
but below formula gives me an error, what am I doing wrong?

```
Worksheets("SINGLE REPORT").Range(Cells(34, 3), Cells(64,22)).FormatConditions.Delete _
    Type:=xlCellTypeBlanks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach (which might be slightly faster):

```
Worksheets("SINGLE REPORT").Range(Cells(34, 3), Cells(64,22)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormatConditions.Delete
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in Type:=xlCellTypeBlanks. Try again without that.

First approach to blank problem

```
For Each cell In Range(Cells(34, 3), Cells(64, 22))

If IsEmpty(cell) Then
cell.FormatConditions.Delete
End If

Next
```